# Not able to see/download old pictures on Facebook messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

So basically I went back about 2 years into an old Facebook conversation and I found some photos that I wanted to view. But they didn't come up as normal photos. They had the file name e.g. "651361361.jpg" on the left and said download on the far right.

Clicking on this does nothing. It doesn't download using the download button and opening in new tab just bring up a white screen. I really want theses photos. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be bug in Facebook that returns a 500 Error when downloading old photos.

You can just alternatively right click and select the option to save the image or open image in a new tab (not open download link)

[image: Save image]